# How can I apply a module to two inputs within the same main.tf?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Currently I am learning terraform, particularly about modules. I have built a module which takes an S3 bucket's arn, applies and creates some policies, and then outputs an arn that will be used by other buckets.

When I apply the module like:

```
module "meow" {
  source                 = "github.com/terraform-modules//woof?ref=00000000000000"
  s3_buckets_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.woof_bar.arn
}
```

The module seems to work.

However, I would like to apply the module to two s3_buckets_arn's. If I reuse the same module in main.tf I will get an error.

I have also tried looping like:

```
locals {
  stuff = {
    name1 = aws_s3_bucket.foo.arn
    name2 = aws_s3_bucket.bar.arn
  }
}

module "meow" {
  for_each = local.stuff
  source                 = "github.com/terraform-modules//woof?ref=00000000000000"
  s3_buckets_arn         = each.value
}
```

But when I plan I get strange naming for resources like:
`module.meow["name2"].bar.foo will be created`

And the arn of the bucket does not seem to be outputted.

How can I apply module to more than one input within the same main.tf? And is it possible to do that with a loop?

For example, I want to be able to do something like:

```
module "meow" {
  source                 = "github.com/terraform-modules//woof?ref=00000000000000"
  s3_buckets_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.foo_one.arn
}

module "meow" {
  source                 = "github.com/terraform-modules//woof?ref=00000000000000"
  s3_buckets_arn         = aws_s3_bucket.foo_two.arn
}
```

(Note: I am using terraform 0.13)

Comment: What error are you seeing?  I think you might just need to give the 2nd instance of the module a different name than `meow` - that name forms part of the module output holding the arn you mention, and thus can't be repeated

Comment: @Thorpe Would that be a reason why the loop I wrote is not working?

Comment: Possibly, but I'm still on TF 0.12 here, so haven't used the loop syntax yet, so can't really comment on how it's supposed to be used!

Comment: Is your issue just that you aren't seeing an output? If you run `terraform state list` do you see the outputs in there as expected? If so can you share how you are outputting at the root context? It looks like you're just failing on that part but it would help if you could edit your question to make it a [mcve] that has your same issue.